# freeze a rigged mixamo character into mesh

Tags: rigging, armature, mixamo

so I have this rigged character that I have downloaded from Mixamo, with a walking animation. I would like to turn it into a statue of sorts, frozen in frame 10. I can accomplish this by manually deleting every single keyframe for every bone, but still if I join it with another mesh it will be distorted beyond repair.

is there any way that I can freeze a rigged character and turn it into a mesh without bones?

Comment: apply the Armature modifier?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a minecraft character rig. Don't know if this will work with Mixamo, but clicking the bones and deleting them retains the mesh. You can join the meshes too and they don't distort.

Comment: I tried that at first but it doesn't work. if I joint two parts of the mesh (ctrl+j) or delete the bones it goes crazy mode.